# css3 prevent vertical image shift

Tags: css

I have image display that shows individual images when a radio button is clicked. however the image associated with the radio button shifts vertically down in it position. in the example below is 3 images with 3 associated radio button.I tried setting line-height to 0 and also tried white-space:nowrap in css. but didn't work. any help is appreciated.

```html
<style>
    #imgflow {
     width: 60%;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align:center;
     margin:0 auto;
    }
    #imf_holder article img {
     width: 100%;
    }
    #imf_holder .inner {
     width: 100%;
     line-height: 0;
    }
    #imf_holder article {
     width: 100%;
    }
    .img-control {
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
    }
    input[type="radio"] ~.ps{
     display:none;
    }
    input[type="radio"]:checked ~.ps{
     display:block;
    
    }
    input[type=radio] {
       opacity: 0;
    }
    </style>
    
    <html>
    <div id="imf_holder">
            <div id="imgflow">
              <div class="inner">
                 <article>
         
        <input type="radio" checked value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-1" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" height="200px" ></div>
        
       </article>
                 <article>
         
        <input type="radio"  value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-2" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images_vwV1tOp.jpg" height="200px" ></div>
        
       </article>
                 <article>
         
        <input type="radio"  value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-3" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" height="200px" ></div>
        
       </article>
     
              </div>
    
            </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;margin-top:15px;">
        <li class="img-control">
          <label for="img-1" >button1  </label>
          <label for="img-2" >button2 </label>
          <label for="img-3" >button3 </label>
    
        </li>
    </div>
```

Comment: i replaced the opacity wit display none as you suggested and that did the trick. appreciate your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `input` to `display: none;`, as when use `opacity` they are invisible but still occupy space, hence pushing the images down.

```
input[type=radio] {
   display: none;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
#imgflow {
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#imf_holder article img {
    width: 100%;
}
#imf_holder .inner {
    width: 100%;
}
#imf_holder article {
    width: 100%;
}
.img-control {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type="radio"] ~ .ps{
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .ps{
    display:block;

}
input[type=radio] {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="imf_holder">
        <div id="imgflow">
          <div class="inner">
             <article>

                <input type="radio" checked value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-1" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" height="200px" ></div>

            </article>
             <article>

                <input type="radio"  value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-2" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://www.hdwallpapery.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images_vwV1tOp.jpg" height="200px" ></div>

            </article>
             <article>

                <input type="radio"  value="Img1"  name="event" id="img-3" ><div class="ps"> <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" height="200px" ></div>

            </article>

          </div>

        </div>

</div>

<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;margin-top:15px;">
    <li class="img-control">
      <label for="img-1" >button1  </label>
      <label for="img-2" >button2 </label>
      <label for="img-3" >button3 </label>

    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `inputs` absolute like this:

```
input[type=radio] {
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```